# BigDecimal#compareTo with different scales

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Why does the following return `1`?

```
new BigDecimal(0.82).setScale(5, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
    .compareTo(new BigDecimal(0.82))
```

I expect this to return `0` because `BigDecimal.compareTo` **ignores scale** according to its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)):

> Compares this `BigDecimal` with the specified `BigDecimal`. Two `BigDecimal` objects that are **equal** in value but have a **different scale** (like `2.0` and `2.00`) are **considered equal by this method**. [...]

Comment: Because `new BigDecimal(0.82)` is `0.81999999999999995115018691649311222136020660400390625
`. **DO NOT** use [`new BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(double)). Use [`BigDecimal.valueOf​(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)): *This is generally the preferred way to convert a `double` (or `float`) into a `BigDecimal`*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new BigDecimal(0.82)` is not actually 0.82, because you're passing a `double` value -- the `double` *closest* to 0.82, which is not exactly 0.82 -- to the constructor, so `new BigDecimal(0.82)` is a `BigDecimal` equal to the `double` closest to 0.82.

Instead, use `new BigDecimal("0.82")`.

Comment: To be specific: `new BigDecimal(0.82)` is 0.81999999999999995115018691649311222136020660400390625. Just print it and see for yourself. And `new BigDecimal(0.82).setScale(5, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)` is 0.82000.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Explain why this affects the `compareTo` and how `setScale` plays a role here.

Comment: If `double` value is not a literal, use [`BigDecimal.valueOf​(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)).

Comment: `setScale` doesn't play a role here, really, other than making the `BigDecimal` equal to `0.82`.

Comment: @Andreas, if your double value is not a literal, you've almost certainly done something wrong already.  Your value should have been a `BigDecimal` in the first place.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not always a choice, if using 3rd-party libraries, or legacy code. Knowing that `new BigDecimal(double)` is **bad**, but there is a good alternative in `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`, is certainly useful information.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I thought setScale would round 0.81999999999999995115018691649311222136020660400390625 to 0.82000. can you explain why the compareTo does not return 0?

Comment: @Zabuza `setScale` did. And 0.82000.compareTo(0.81999999999999995115018691649311222136020660400390625) is supposed to be >0

Comment: You don't need to explain this to me. It was meant more as a comment to edit and improve the answer. Because currently it answers the question only indirect.

Comment: @Zabuza Then say that in a comment. Don't ask like you don't know, because then you'll just get answers to the comment like I just did.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use the constructor `BigDecimal#BigDecimal(double)`. It returns a `BigDecimal` that represents the double's **binary floating-point value** (see its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(double))). However, `0.82` isn't representing the value `0.82` but

```
0.81999999999999995115018691649311222136020660400390625
```

Because of that `.setScale(5, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)` actually **changes the value**, not only the scale. The resulting value after applying the method is

```
0.82000
```

The `compareTo` method ignores the scale but not **different values**. As explained, your two `BigDecimal` actually represent different values. Thus the `compareTo` does not return `0`:

```
0.82000 != 0.81999999999999995115018691649311222136020660400390625
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)) of the method:

> Two `BigDecimal` objects that are **equal in value** but have a different scale (like `2.0` and `2.00`) are considered equal by this method. [...]